# Flutter State Management: How can I prevent the widget rebuilding

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, state-management

I fetch a list from an api, which list has some fields already defined. I want to write on some of the fields and send it back, so I use a **Form** and under the form I use a Consumer and a Listview.seperated to represent the list. On the fields I want to write I use a textformfield. All of these are working correctly, except one issue. When I tap outside the textformfields the ui rebuilds again and the fields take their initial values. Is it possible to prevent that ui rebuild using Selector instead of Consumer?

```
Form(
              key: _calendarFormKey,
              child: Consumer<CalendarViewProvider>(
                builder: (context, cal, child) {
                  if (cal.length == 0) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text('List is empty'),
                    );
                  } else {
                    textControllers.clear();
                    int? numOfControllers = cal.length;
                    for (int i = 0; i < numOfControllers; i++) {
                      textControllers.add(TextEditingController());
                    }

                    return ListView.separated(
                        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return SizedBox(height: 10);
                        },
                        itemCount: cal.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          var _cale = cal[index];

                          textControllers[index].text =
                              '${_cale.description}';

                          void clearController() {
                            context
                                .read<CalendarViewProvider>()
                                .removeCalendar(code: _cale.code);
                            textControllers[index].clear();
                          }

                          addToList(String text) {
                            caleList.clear();
                            for (int i = 0; i < numOfControllers; i++) {
                              var _cal = cal[i];
                              Map<String, dynamic> caleData = {
                                'code': _cal.code,
                                'start': _cal.start,
                                'end': _cal.end,
                                'title': _cal.title,
                                'description': textControllers[i].text,
                              };
                              caleList.add(caleData);
                            }
                          }

                          return Container(
                            height: ScreenConfig.screenHeight * .08,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(width: 3),
                                Text(
                                  _cale.start?.substring(11, 16) ?? '',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.grey[600]),
                                ),
                                Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset(
                                      AppImages.dietDayImg,
                                      height:
                                          ScreenConfig.screenHeight * .15,
                                      width: ScreenConfig.screenWidth * .21,
                                    ),
                                    Positioned.fill(
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          _cale.title?.substring(0, 1) ??
                                              '',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 1),
                                SingleChildScrollView(
                                  child: Container(
                                    height:
                                        ScreenConfig.screenHeight * .078,
                                    width: ScreenConfig.screenWidth * .55,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Color(0xFFd6e7ea),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(10),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        controller: textControllers[index],
                                        maxLines: 20,
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          border: InputBorder.none,
                                        ),
                                        onSaved: (newValue) {
                                          addToList(
                                              textControllers[index].text);
                                          textControllers[index].text =
                                              newValue!;
                                        },
                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                          caleList[index]['description'] =
                                              value;
                                          addToList(
                                              textControllers[index].text);
                                          textControllers[index].text =
                                              value;
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    deleteDialog();
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  iconSize: 12,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: In my opinion a rebuild should never really change your state. You should code in a way with the assumption that `build` could be called at any time. The problem in your code is that you are creating new `TextEditingControllers` every time you build. The creation of those should be handled outside the `build`

Comment: I am trying to find the right way to do it, because a range error occurs.

Comment: I followed your approach and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my existing code I deleted the declaration of the textfield controllers under the list I created. I put the results of the api inside a list, and I declare the controllers based on that list so, these textfields don't rebuild again. I put my code under the Widget build and over the return:

```
var list = context.watch<CalendarViewProvider().calendarView?.results;
list?.forEach((element) {
  element.description;
  var controller = TextEditingController(text: element.description);
  textControllers.add(controller);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you taged (but not mentioned) provider, I assume that you are using provider. If you are filling "cal" in the build method with something like:

```
final cal = Provider.of<T>(context);
```

It will always update. You can fill cal in initstate.
But maybe you have also to do (here I am guessing, since I can only see your "Form-Code") or it can also work if you use "AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin". Here for you have to make the Widget what you want to keep alife to stateful then add like that

```
class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Normaly you dont need to call super in Flutter for State<T>. But since we using [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin],
    /// we have to call it. In Flutter is super used to call the constructor of the base Class.
    super.build(context);
return.....;
}
/// this is also important
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. In init state I call the provider to hit the api and return the list. The cal is from the provider that is used in Consumers builder. It isn't defined somewhere else. Under the build method, I call 2 more providers to show other fields from this page. None of them are related to the Consumers provider

Comment: You have to preload the data and then fill. Otherwise it will reset when it is loading again and this providing will always force to rebuild (as long as the data are not the same)

Comment: I load the data when I enter the homepage after splash screen. I enter the page that the list is displayed and it still has the same behaviour

Comment: Its not about the loading. Its about delivering. You have to preload it and deliver it as a Variable to the child. And if that also not working, you are rebuilding your child, so that is the problem what you have to solve then. You already tried AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin?

Comment: Yes I did and nothing changed. When I remove this line: textControllers[index].text='${_cale.description}'; and the texteditingcontrollers dont take value, when I add value and tap outside the state doesn't change and the values remain as I added them.

Comment: I dont get it, you said you are loading all the data static. You know as long as you building from a Consumer, you are not preloading the data from the api and using the preloaded. It will itself use the data from the provider! And why it works when you remove that line is, because I assume that _cale is a provided data. And this will update it.

Comment: Sry I cant help more then that. Maybe Try to update your whole code with the whole *.dart file. I dont know.

Comment: I never talked about static load. The list comes from an api, dynamically, and some fields already have values, which I change and then I send back the list as a form. I am sorry if you understand something else, I tried to explained it as good as I could. I can provide you my whole code. Is there a way to have a more direct conversation here in stuck overflow?

Comment: That is a lot of code. I am not able to help you more than this atm.  Try to update your code with more. Or let it like it is and add a link to where you provide whole code. Maybe when I find some time, I can help you the following days.

Comment: I found something that works for now. I followed @Ivo advice and i created the text editing controllers outside the build of the consumer, using the provider fetching the list length. And fortunatelly it doesnt rebuild the controllers when the state changes.

Comment: Then please post your solution as an answer and accept it, so it helps also other people :)